# Ant Design add text only menu items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I want to add a simple text item to my [Ant Design Menu](https://ant.design/components/menu/), something like:

```
<Menu>
  <Menu.Item key={to} style={style}><a href="/page1"> Page 1</a></Menu.Item>
  <Menu.Item key={to} style={style}><a href="/page2"> Page 2</a></Menu.Item>
  <span>Non clickable text</span>
</Menu>
```

This displays fine but it gives me a ton of errors in the console:

> index.js:2178 Warning: React does not recognize the `subMenuKey` prop
>   on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as
>   a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `submenukey` instead. If you
>   accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM
>   element.

Does anybody have a way around this ? I really like that Menu component so don't feel like rewriting my own.

Comment: why don't get rid of `<a href=...` and instead `onClick={() => document.location = '/page1'} `?

Comment: @Alex that part is working fine, what I want is to be able to display the span at the end without errors

Answer (score 10):

As indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51847359/742299), the issue is that you are trying to include a `<Divider />` IN your Menu, and Menu has a limited list of children it will accept. `<Divider />` is not one of the acceptable children.

If you remove the `<Divider />` element, those warnings will go away.  I actually ran into this myself.

Change your references to

```
<Menu.Divider />
```

and you will be gucci.

Comment: Thanks. I am out of that project so can't test. If anyone can confirm that this works, I'll accept.

Comment: This doesn't work. Putting a `span` or `div` inside of `a-menu` causes this error.

Comment: Any idea of adding a text to Menu.Divider tag?

Comment: This worked for me. Example: `<Menu><Menu.Item key='1'>Item 1</Menu.Item><Menu.Divider /><Menu.Item key='2'>Item 2</Menu.Item></Menu>`

Answer (score 8):

Menu tag only accept Menu.Item, SubMenu and Menu.ItemGroup as children.
Menu.Item only accepts disabled and key as props. Other than those, if you use custom html tags, you will face those errors in console.

And also, as per ant docs we need to use style tag at menu level instead of menu.item

My suggestion is to remove anchor tag to eliminate just redirect part for text or you can use disabled={true} to display text in disabled manner..

```
<Menu.Item key="3"  disabled={true}>Non clickable text </Menu.Item>
```

Comment: I have tried that and unfortunately it didnt work, the CSS for disabled is set a `!important` in the library which makes it hard to override (and very hacky)

Answer (score 5):

Try empty [ItemGroup](https://ant.design/components/menu/#Menu.ItemGroup):

```
<Menu.ItemGroup title="Non clickable text" />
```

Comment: No luck :( I am using an horizontal Menu -__- Thanks for the help tho

Comment: Works for me with an horizontal menu (antd 3.23.2)!

Comment: Works for me with a vertical menu!

Answer (score 1):

I had to create custom menu with react and used standard label tag:

```
 <ul style={{ display: 'flex', listStyle: 'none' }}>
        <li><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>
        <Divider
          style={{width: 0}} 
          type="vertical" />       
        <li><Link to='/books'>Books</Link></li>
        <Divider
          style={{width: 0}} 
          type="vertical"/>

      <li><Link to='/authors'>Authors</Link></li>  // clickable menu 
      <Divider
          style={{width: 0}} 
          type="vertical"/>
      <li><label>Example</label></li>   // some non-clickable text
      </ul>
```

If you want to use the original menu the only way I see is that was mentioned below:

```
<Menu>
    <Menu.Item><a href="/Page1"> Page 1</a></Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item><a href="/Page2"> Page 2</a></Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item> some non-clickable text </Menu.Item>
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a custum `SubMenu` component to fix this issue:

```
export interface SubMenuProp {
  className?: string;
  submenukey?: string;
  children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[];
}

const SubMenu = (props: SubMenuProp) => {
  return <div className={props.className}>{props.children}</div>;
};

export default SubMenu;
```

So you can use it like:

```
<Menu>
    <Menu.Item><a href="/Page1"> Page 1</a></Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item><a href="/Page2"> Page 2</a></Menu.Item>
    <SubMenu> some non-clickable text </SubMenu>
</Menu>
```

The reason why there's an error messege for a normal element is because the sub menu item is lack of a `submenukey` prop. However I'm still unsure about if there's any issues if I leave it to undefined.